# how to get size of View's contents

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a class that derives from `ImageView`. In its `onDraw` method override I need to copy the view's contents into a bitmap. The copy must contain the whole contents not just the visible portion.

To accomplish this I create a bitmap and invoke `super.onDraw` passing this bitmap's canvas as the parameter. I then draw the resulting bitmap to the canvas that `onDraw` was passed. The code is below.

My question is how big my bitmap should be? Currently I use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` as the bitmap's dimensions. But this does not work because it returns the view size, not the contents size. I am looking for a way to get the size of the contents after the drawable has been resized according to the view's `scaleType`.

The size of the drawable does not work because the drawable can be different from the contents dimensions.

`@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (_bitmap == null)
        {
            final int w = getWidth();
            final int h = getHeight();

            _bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            _canvas = new Canvas(_bitmap);

            super.onDraw(_canvas);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }`

Comment: What's the question then?? Isn't the code working??

Comment: I have edited the question and changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into

[getDrawingCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29)(boolean autoScale)

Returns the bitmap in which this view drawing is cached.

Set autoScale to true.

Answer (score 0):

This way you get dimensions after measurement and layout. You should get the underlying Drawable and call [getIntrinsicWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicWidth%28%29) i guess

Comment: thank you, but this does not work, I have edited the question to clarify